# What is the firestore equivalent of this.db.object?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

Using this concept / tutorial for a project (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/custom-usernames-with-firebase-authentication-and-angular/) 
However it is in firebase, I need the Firestore equivalent.

I have tried the following:

```
  checkUsername(tag: string) {
    console.log('Checking Username: ' + username);
    return  this.afs.collection('usernames', ref => ref.where('username', '==', tag)).valueChanges();
  }
```

I would like to only retrieve that specific field in the collection and check if it is available or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to listen for changes via snapShotChanges/valueChanges.

Just do a simple get with a limit(1) (we don't care if there are more than 1 username) and check if the size is > 0. If > 0 => username taken, otherwise username is available:

```
const db = firebase.firestore()

const isUserNameTaken = async (tag: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  const query = db.collection('usernames').where('username', '==', tag).limit(1)
  const docs = await query.get()
  return !!docs.size
}

// returns true if username taken otherwise returns false

const isTaken = await isUserNameTaken('John')
if (isTaken) // do something
```

Comment: Thanks Firebaser! I have added the above to the constructor but I am getting the below error:

Comment: Type 'boolean' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.ts(1055)

Comment: Yeah sorry, the function must returns a Promise of type boolean. Updated my post @Badger29

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this with AngularFirestore Library? I have declared in my constructor ```private afs: AngularFirestore```

Comment: I believe Angularfire2 has a get() method but i'm not sure at all. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs